# How can I set the visibility of an element from another class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a little program with an extra class. In the `Main` Thread I start another thread that starts a method in that class. Now I will set the visibility of a label from the class. I have tried to do that so:

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
...
main.lable.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

The program gives me the error that the Thread must be a `STA-Thread`.

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread that modifies the UI must be **STA thread**. Moreover it must have a message loop, so we are talking about your application *main thread*. You can read more about WPF threading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx).

The point is that you have to use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

To solve your problem, supposing that `lable` is public, in your secondary thread try to use this code:

```
main.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    new Action(() => main.lable.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
```

I hope this can help you.

**EDIT**

I edit my answer with a simple example about updating UI from a secondary thread:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task task = new Task(new Action(() => ExecuteOnSeparateThread()));
        task.Start();
    }

    private void ExecuteOnSeparateThread()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            new Action(() => Label.Foreground = Brushes.Red));
    }
}
```

I do not know your complete code, so I can just help you by providing an example which can lead you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that dosn't work... the problem is that every time when I try to create a new 'MainWindow' (MainWindow main = new MainWindow()) the programm stops at the point in the MainWindow.xaml.cs where the constructor is. and the error is that i have to use a STA thread.

Comment: @TobiasFink You should never need to new up a `MainWindow`, your `App.xaml` should have a `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` inside of it and  that is what starts your first window.